# How to forward data from one page to another

Tags: asp.net

I want to take my data tables data to another page. How can I do this? I am programming in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

You can use QueryString to pass data.

Comment: how can i use query string for passing a data table to other page

Comment: If this data table is populated via server, so you can do it again vai query string.
But if this data table is changed on the client, so this page should be posted back and then you can redirect your page.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

If the data is the same on all pages use the **Cache**. Otherwise retrieve the data again from the database.

Also you can take a look at this article about possible ways of state management in ASP.NET: [Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as a session variable:

```
Session['yourData'] = dataYouWantToPass;
```

Then in the next page you retrieve it like so:

```
var dataYouWantToPass = (YourDataType)Session['yourData'];
```

In case of string data it would look like this:

```
//store in session
Session['stringData'] = "Test string data";

//read from session
var stringData= (String)Session['stringData'];
```

Comment: I would suggest against a session variable when possible because you can lose scalability (non-serializable objects make session in SQL not possible) and can cause for confusing code.

Comment: Agreed, however, I still think it's better than passing it via the QueryString.

Comment: But I have a lot of data too pass is it a god solution using session without degrading the performance. or any alternate is there.